# Should we replace laravel hasone relation return null in to object array?

Tags: php, laravel

When the Laravel relationship returns null in hasOne then how to convert it into object array?

Comment: why do you want to do that??

Comment: Please update your question to be clearer and provide a code sample of what you're talking about. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: As in return a default if one doesn't exist? Also, what do you mean by "object array"?

Comment: When we used hasOne relationship in laravel getting response in object array like {}.. but hasOne relation return null then facing issue from mobile(Android) side in Api. In Mobile side needed blank object array when relation data not found not needed blank or null